# Cannot bind a plain reference to a literal?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
auto &h = 42;        // error：we can't bind a plain reference to a literal.
const auto &j = 42;  // right
```

I don't understand why compiler can't know `&h` is `const int&
I mean ,"auto" is have two step:1.know what type of rvalue.
                                2.make sure lvalue become the type
if the step is right,why we must add "const" when rvalue is literal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do const references extend the lifetime of rvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues)

Comment: You should know that it isn't `const int&`, the compiler isn't confused. It's an `int` pure rvalue. The fact a const reference binds to it, doesn't mean it's of a const reference type.

Comment: @StoryTeller _You should know_ sounds a lot like _C++ is an expert-friendly language_ indeed. :-D

Comment: @skypjack - We must accept it for what it is, and love it no less :P

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @StoryTeller "The fact a const reference binds to it, doesn't mean it's of a const reference type",why not? I still couldn't understand@_@

Comment: @StoryTeller  Oh, I see. That's why.you mean is the type on either side of the equals sign is unlikeliness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` never deduces a `const` when the input was non-const. Since `42` has type `int`,  then `auto` deduces to `int` and your code is equivalent to:

```
int& h = 42;
```

which is an error because a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a prvalue.