# Binding a const pointer reference to a non-const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int val2 = 38;
int *ptr = &val2;
const int *&ptrRef = ptr; // ERROR

int i = 92;
int &ref_i = i;
const int &ref_i2 = ref_i;  // OK
```

Why I can't have a const reference that references to a non-const pointer? I thought that if you access the const `ptrRef` identifier, it will treat `val2` as const. When you access `ptr`, it will treat `val2` as non-const. This works for the bottom part of the code, so I don't understand why it won't work for pointers.

Comment: Why would you want something flagged as a `const` to not actually *be* a `const`?

Comment: Did you mean `int* const& ptrRef = ptr;`?

Comment: @ScottHunters why not? `const` reference to non-const objects are everywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[East-const](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt) makes it clearer:

```
int const * & ptrRef = ptr; // ERROR
```

It's the pointer that is const. However, `ptr` is a different type. You can't bind a reference to a different type. It requires a conversion, making the initializer a temporary (`ptr` converted to `int const*`).

> Now, there's a more confusing catch: const references **can** bind to temporaries, extending their lifetime: [Why do const references extend the lifetime of rvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues/39718826)
>
> They e.g. allow funtions to take arguments by `const&` and still be callable with temporaries:
>
> ```
> void foo(std::string const&);
>
> foo("foor"s+"bar"s); // still ok
> ```

Comment: I do not think it is anachronism. Binding const references to temporaries is still an important feature.

Comment: @SergeyA amended

Answer (score 4):

I think, your question boils to a simple typo. If you want a const reference to non-const pointer, use following:

```
int* const&  ptrRef = ptr; // no error
```

This declares ptrRef as a const reference to non-const pointer. Another, perhaps cleaner option, is to introduce a typedef:

```
 using intptr = int *;
 const intptr& ptrRef = ptr;
```

Additionally, you can get out of business of manually specifying the type altogether:

```
const auto&  ptrRef = ptr; // no error
```

And, for good measure, this would work (as in compile) too, if that is what you want:

```
const int* const&  ptrRef = ptr; // no error
```

The latest bit declares constant reference to a constant pointer.

Comment: `int* const&  ptrRef = ptr;` is a "non-const reference to a const `int*` pointer", not a "const reference to a non-const `int*` pointer", like you claim.  `const` applies to the thing on its left (in this case, the `int*` pointer), unless there is nothing there then it applies to the thing on its right instead. In `const int *&ptrRef = ptr;`, the `const` applies to the `int`being pointed at, not to the `int*` pointer.