# Why does converting an rvalue into an lvalue ref not raise a warning?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know, why the following code does not raise a warning?

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int a = 1;
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo getString()
    {
        return Foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar a;
    const Foo& b = a.getString();   <--- Foo getString() becomes Foo&?
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GYzWa7

Comment: There's nothing to warn about. By binding a const reference to the temporary returned by getString it's lifetime is extended to match the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: @John I think you should turn that comment into a proper answer.

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @JesperJuhl I wasn't completely sure I was answering the question that the OP was asking. They might have some other reason for thinking a warning was needed.

Comment: That's fine! Thanks a lot! That would exactly answer my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues

Comment: OK now it's an official answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing to warn about. By binding a `const` reference to the temporary returned by `getString` its lifetime is extended to match the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: Related question : [Does a const reference class member prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-class-member-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).