# c++ reference erro

Tags: c++, reference

my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 100;

int func();

int main()
{
    int c = 10;
    int & d = c;
//  int & b = func();
    int & b = a;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}

int func()
{
    return a;
}
```

if I open the commment line. My g++ compiler will prompt error `cannot bind non-const lvalue referrence of type int& to an rvalue of type int`. This is so strange. This statement is so similar to its next line  `int & b = a`. Why its next line can work well and do not prompt the same error.

And another strange is after I modify my func definition which I modify its return type form `int` to `int &` the g++ will not prompt the error.

I usually use java and I just learn c++ last week. I need some experts help.

Answer (score 3):

> This statement is so similar to its next line `int & b = a`. Why its next line can work well and do not prompt the same error.

The next line works because `a` is an lvalue. Lvalues can be bound to lvalue references (of compatible type). Rvalues cannot be bound to lvalue references to non-const types.

> And another strange is after I modify my func definition which I modify its return type form int to int & the g++ will not prompt the error.

This is because a call to function that returns an lvalue reference is also an lvalue expression.

Comment: OK. According your explanation, func returns `int` stands for it return rvalue, no matter what it returns in fact, in my code it return a global var.

Comment: @MelvinLevett Yes. A call to a function that returns an object is always a prvalue.

Comment: And what puzzles me is when I modify my func return type like what I said last. Its siganature is `int &` but it just return var `a` in fact (which is `int` not `int &`) and the g++ will not prompt type imcompatitable.

Comment: @MelvinLevett It returns a *temporary copy* of the global value. C++ makes much greater use of Value semantics than Java does. See [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). You're going to have to ignore a lot of your Java language knowledge when working with C++.

Comment: @MelvinLevett `a` expression is an lvalue of type `int`. Such value can be bound to a reference also when returning that reference, exactly as it can be bound when initialising a reference variable.

Comment: @errorika I have known a little from your explanation. I need more reading. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
int & b = func();
```

and

```
 int & b = a;
```

define a [lvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

`a` is an lvalue. `b` can refer to it.

`func()` does not return the global variable `a`. It returns a temporary copy of `a`,  a prvalue. This result is so short lived, it expires at the end of the line, that taking a reference to it is pointless. The returned value will be invalid before you can use the reference, so the compiler's protecting you from a runtime error.

But if you make a `const` reference,

```
const int & b = func();
```

the compiler will perform [some deep magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues) to preserve the returned value

Handy reading: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)