# C++ Return const reference from function with temporary parameter of custom non-duplicable object

Tags: c++

I am struggling with miniproject, where I have to do this

```
const Foo &f = func(arr(1.3, 2.4, 3.8, 4.3));
```

`Foo` is non-duplicable class containing single `float` value as memeber, `arr` is simple function that returns `std::vector` of `Foo` objects initialized with values passed as parameter into `arr`.
Finally `func` is defined as following:

```
const Foo &func(const std::vector<Foo> &in)
{
    return *std::max_element(in.begin(), in.end());
}
```

`Foo` has defined `operator<` function, that determines which of the two `Foo`s have bigger value, thus `std::max_element` works as should. `Foo` has also defined `Foo(Foo &&v)` that copies value.

I know that parameter of `func` is created as temporary.

Application is compilable, but after debugging, the object `f` contains some random value, that is not even in passed array (since the object was already destroyed?).

Is there any possible way to change `func` so this will work?

Comment: The result will be a dangling reference.  That's bad.  The way around it is to not pass in a temporary.  Or don't return a reference.

Comment: Is there any possible way to change `func` so this will work? I cannot change line where the `func` is called and result assigned.

Comment: `Foo func(...)` would work.  Return a value.

Comment: Return by value. `const Foo& f = ` will extend the lifetime of the returned temporary until the end of the enclosing scope.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues

Comment: `Foo func(std::vector<Foo> const& v) { auto result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end()); if (result == v.end()) throw "oopsies"; return *result; }`

Comment: Function code is valid, since reference to element of container passed to argument is returned. The only case when it can fail is when container is empty. Problem is that to argument temporary object is passed, so basically this line is wrong: `const Foo &f = func(arr(1.3, 2.4, 3.8, 4.3));`

Comment: @Eljay I think this wouldn't work because of deleted copy constructor of `Foo`.

Comment: Is your type movable? If so, it should be possible to return by value by moving the variable out from the vector.

Comment: @alterigel this is not this case. If `func` would return a value then linked topic kicks in. Here is Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Brykyz how about move? Move constructor could do the job here.

Comment: @MarekR I have never worked with move constructor, I was reading documentation. Anyway, it did the job! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `func` were to return by value, it would return a temporary object whose lifetime would be extended to that of `f`.

However, the object needs to be moved from the input array since it cannot be copied. This is a problem because the input parameter is a `const` reference. So provide an overload that takes a movable parameter that can bind to a temporary vector. This could be either receiving by value or taking a non-`const` r-value reference.

```cpp
Foo func(std::vector<Foo> && in)
// ^     ^----------------^^------- non-const r-vlaue reference
// |------------------------------- return a temporary, not a reference
{
    return std::move(*std::max_element(in.begin(), in.end()));
    //     ^^^^^^^^^--------------------- move the result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of `func` is a reference to an element of the `vector` passed to it, then you must ensure that the `vector` argument is still alive when you access the result. Passing a temporary object (`arr(1.3, 2.4, 3.8, 4.3)`) means that vector will be destroyed as soon as `func` is evaluated and thus the reference returned is no good. Call `func` without a temporary vector parameter and you should be fine:

```cpp
auto func_arg = arr(1.3, 2.4, 3.8, 4.3);
const Foo &f = func(func_arg);
```

There's nothing you can change within `func` to make the returned reference valid. The input must be a non-temporary.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that bit. Edited back out.