# const class can extend lifetime of const member ref of temporary?

Tags: c++, lifetime, temporary

```
struct  A {

// something

~A() { std::cout <<  "A destruct!\n"; }

};

class  refWrapper {

public:

refWrapper(const  A&  a) : a_(a) {}

~refWrapper() { std::cout <<  "refWrapper destruct!\n"; }

private:

const A& a_;

};

void  func(const  refWrapper&  ref  =  A()) {

// why ~A after ~refWrapper

// Rather than after refWrapper constructor complete

}
```

Comment: Please use the code layout tool to format your question correctly.  And it's helpful to elaborate on your question with more than just a code example.

Comment: do you have code that you compiled and executed to get output different from what you expected? If so, please include a [mcve] (where is your `main`?) and actual and expected output in the question

Comment: What is the question? Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues

Comment: @ypnos: notice that there are 2 temporaries: a `refWrapper` which is bound to `ref`, and `A()`.

Comment: outside of function call, behavior is different [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb17509322c6caf7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default arguments, the call

```
func();
```

is equivalent to

```
func(A()); // so func(refWrapper(A()));
```

So,

- temporary `A` is created first (destroyed at end of full expression)
- temporary `refWrapper` is created second (bound to parameter reference)
- temporary `refWrapper` destroyed.
- temporary `A` destroyed.

Notice that there is an [exception for lifetime extension or parameter](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9):

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

So `refWrapper` is destroyed at end of full expression, and not at the end of `func` call (which is the same moment in given example though). So destruction should be done in reverse order of construction.