# Why don't const l-value references to r-values result in dangling references?

Tags: c++

Why is the following not an error?

```
const auto& foo = std::string("foo");
```

In my mental model of C++ I think of references as glorified non-null pointers that the language wraps in syntactic sugar for me. However the code below would be an error but the above is not.

```
const auto* foo = &(std::string("foo"));
```

In the reference case why is the string not immediately destructed after the r-value expression is evaluated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718268/why-do-const-references-extend-the-lifetime-of-rvalues

Comment: You need to adjust your mental model.

Comment: Why do you call it a "const l-value reference"? Isn't that normally just called an "r-value reference"?

Comment: just meant that `foo` is a reference and it is l-value since it has a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is the language rule [Lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference.

There is no such rule for const pointers.